# Javascript: How to call a method from a constructor? My variable returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, class, dictionary, for-loop, svg

I am creating a javascript class to handle SVG tags in HTML. (I know that there are plenty of classes that does this already but I did not succeed with transformations via svg.js. Also, I have made all the required functions to work and I just want to implement them as a class for syntactical ease.)

However, not being that familiar with javascript, I have trouble with a variable that is set to `Undefined` in my constructor:

```
class SLD {
    constructor(container,x=1000, y=1000) {
        this.ctn = document.getElementById(container);
        this.svgobj = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        // Defining object attributes  
        var obj = {
            'width': "1000",
            'height': "1000",
            'xmlns':"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 
            'version':"1.1",
            'xmlns:xlink':"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        };
        // Setting attribute via for loop
        for(prop in obj) {
            this.svgobj.setAttribute(prop, obj[prop])  
        }
    }
```

While trying to run it, I am returned the following error code:
[image]

How do I define the variable properly? I am using Chrome (version 83.0.4103.116) and the browser supports classes as far as I am noticed.

Let me know if I should provide any other relevant information.

Comment: You haven't declared `prop` anywhere, and `class` code is always strict, so you get the error (rather than the much worse alternative -- an implicit global). Add `const` in front of `prop`: `for (const prop in obj)`.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into the question. If you feel the need to write an answer then write one as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume prop hasn't been declared yet so you'll need to use var.

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    this.svgobj.setAttribute(prop, obj[prop])  
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was the solution. I was surprised that my code actually worked in a general function but made trouble when trying to implement it into a class. I think this might be a case of a pythonic mistake (not to think about declaring the identifier of variables). Cheers and God speed!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
for (const prop in obj) {
  this.svgobj.setAttribute(prop, obj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable declaration was your problem.

Your code could be optimized by replacing the **for** loop with:

```
Object.entries({
    'width': "20",
    'height': "20",
    'xmlns':"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 
    'version':"1.1",
    'xmlns:xlink':"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
}).forEach(([prop,value])=>svgobj.setAttribute(prop, value));
```